# How do i access .word data 'source', increment to each number, assign to 'destination'?

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

Trying to access and iterate through each number in 'source' until i hit a 0, then save these numbers to the same 'destination' index.

Tried: Many a thing, not able to access the .word data properly. unsure why..

```
.data
source:     .word   3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 0
dest:       .word   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
countmsg:   .asciiz " values copied. "

.text

main:   add $s0,    $0,     $ra # Save our return address
    la  $t0,    source
    la  $t1,    dest


loop:   lw  $t3,    ($t0)       # read next word from source
    beq $t3,    $zero,  loopend # loopend if word is 0
    addi    $t4,    $t4,1       # increment count words copied
    sw  $t3,    0($t1)      # write to destination
    addi    $t0,    $t0,1       # advance pointer to next source
    addi    $t1,    $t1,1       # advance pointer to next dest
    j loop
loopend:

    move    $a0,    $v0     # We want to print the count
    li  $v0,    1
    syscall             # Print it
    la  $a0,    countmsg    # We want to print the count msg
    li  $v0,    4
    syscall             # Print it
    li  $a0,    0x0A        # We want to print '\n'
    li  $v0,    11
    syscall             # Print it
    jr  $s0         # Return from main. $ra in $s0
```

not aligned on word boundary, unsure how to make the iteration line up

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the way you increment array pointers. `word` is 4 bytes wide and accessing next element requires to add 4 to address. This definitely explains why you have unaligned accesses.

There are a couple of other problems.

`main` is a special function and you should not return from main, but call exit() (`syscall 10`)

And the word count is in `$t4` and was not printed correctly.

I also modified your loop, in order to have a unique branch in it and to suppress the final jump. It is always better to do the test at the end of loop in a do-while way.

Here is a corrected version:

```
.data
source:     .word   3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 0
dest:       .word   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
countmsg:   .asciiz " values copied. "

.text

main:   ### main is a special function. Should not save $ra
            #### $ra add $s0,    $0,     $ra # Save our return address
    la  $t0,    source
    la  $t1,    dest

loop:    lw  $t3,    ($t0)   # read next word from source
    addi $t4,    $t4,1       # increment count words copied
    sw   $t3,    0($t1)      # write to destination
    addi $t0,    $t0,4       # advance pointer to next source
        ### increment must be sizeof(word), ie 4
    addi $t1,    $t1,4       # advance pointer to next dest
    bne  $t3,$zero, loopend # loopend while word is != 0
        ### no longer required    j loop
loopend:

    move $a0,    $t4    # We want to print the count
                            # which is in $t4    
    li  $v0,    1
    syscall             # Print it
    la  $a0,    countmsg    # We want to print the count msg
    li  $v0,    4
    syscall             # Print it
    li  $a0,    0x0A        # We want to print '\n'
    li  $v0,    11
    syscall             # Print it
    li  $a0,    0       # EXIT_SUCCESS
    li  $v0,    10
    syscall             # exit
##    jr  $s0         # NO Return from main. use exit syscall
```